# How can I get a JSON data from a WebAPI with VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to get a JSON data from a WebAPI though, I have no idea about how to solve with VB.NET. The code below was  I pasted and made from some article on the internet.
Actually I don't know whether I need the command by name of "**Await**" or not, and how to use it. I'm faced a syntax error from this area. Could someone help me??
According to the supplier of the API, I apparently need to put a value called 'token' on their header when I connect to that URL.
(ASP.NET4.6/VB.NET/VisualStudio2017)

```
url = "https://webapi.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXX.com/getuserno?employeeid=" & txtID.Text
Dim str As String
Using client = New Http.HttpClient()   
      client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("XXX-Api-Access-Token", jsonObj("access_token"))
      client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)
      Dim dt As System.IO.Stream = Await client.GetStreamAsync(url)
      Dim sr0 As New System.IO.StreamReader(dt, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
      str = sr0.ReadToEnd()
      dt.Close()
End Using
```

I changed like this, but still am facing two syntax errors where I call the function.

1: Await-> BC37058 'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

2: AccessTheWebAsync-> End of statement expected

```
    Dim content As String = Await AccessTheWebAsync(jsonObj("access_token"))
End Sub

Async Function AccessTheWebAsync(ByVal jsonObj As Object) As Threading.Tasks.Task
        url = "https://webapi.XXXXXXXXX.XXXXX.com/getuserno?employeeid=" & txtID.Text
        Dim str As String
        Using client = New Http.HttpClient()

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("XXX-Api-Access-Token", jsonObj("access_token"))
            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10.0)

            Dim dt As System.IO.Stream = Await client.GetStreamAsync(url) 
            Dim sr0 As New System.IO.StreamReader(dt, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            str = sr0.ReadToEnd()
            dt.Close()

        End Using
End Function
```

Comment: What is the syntax error ? Can you please put the error text here ?

Comment: Hi Aditya, I can see these letters on my screen. BC37058 'Await' can only be used within an Async method. Consider marking this method with the 'Async' modifier and changing its return type to 'Task'.

Comment: Then just put your code inside Async Function. Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: I really appreciate it, Aditya. I followed your advise, but was I make mistaking? Could you check the comment I added above?? If you continue to help, I'm so happy. Thank you.